# Does the size of a column affect write speed?

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis

More than just the size of the data itself I mean.  I am currently creating SSIS packages for simple refreshes from Production to Test.  I have two tables, one that is 2.5GB in size and another that is 1.5GB in size.  The 2.5GB table has a few hundred thousand rows and refreshes properly. However, the other table has only 8,000 rows, but whoever originally created this table and system decided to use it to store PDF files (resulting in a column with a rather ridiculous amount of data) and I have not been able to get it moved, despite it actually containing less data than the other table.

If this is indeed the case, is there a better way to refresh the table?

Comment: How exactly do you define "refresh"? Update/insert/delete, MERGE, truncate/re-populate?

Comment: Delete destination, insert the data from source.

Comment: So is it the delete that's slow, or the insert? And if it can be done in the background without really affecting users, does it matter how long it takes? If not, then maybe look at this: http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/t-sql-tuesday-schema-switch-a-roo

Comment: The data flow is an in-memory ETL engine. When you have data that doesn't fit in memory, your SSIS performance goes to hell. If your query source evaluates to DT_IMAGE, SSIS is going to carry a pointer in memory and write all the data for that **row** to disk and when it's time to write it to the destination it will then read that one row's data back off disk and then do the insert. Depending on where/whether you have defined your blob storage location, it's probably beating on your C: drive.